# Querying Couchbase view by passing parameter

Tags: javascript, couchbase, couchbase-view

I have Couchbase notification documents stored in below format:

```
{
    "_id":"notification::5403cb1a6c965dcfe9",
    "alert":"test data",
    "body":{
        "created_by":"user_54986e326694f10e511cf",
        "description":" reported ",

    },
    "channels":[
        "user_54986e326694f10e511cf",
        "user_54986e326694f10e511cp"
    ],
    "notification_type":"new_report",
    "seen":true,
    "timestamp":"2015-01-06T15:48:25.092Z",
    "type":"notification"
}
```

The JSON document contains `channels` array, it is a list of `user_id` who subscribe to channels. Problem is I have to emit notification document if chaneel field contain `user_id`, if I pass `user_id ='user_54986e326694f10e511cf'` pass as key parameter.

Below is my Couchbase view map function but it doesn't return anything

```
function (doc, meta) {
  if(doc.type=='notification' && doc.channels){

        for (var user in doc.channels) {
            emit(user, {
                alert: doc.alert,
                body: doc.body,
                seen: doc.seen,
                timestamp: doc.timestamp
            });

        }

    }
}
```

I am wondering where i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Those "alert", "body", "seen" etc that you're emitting as *keys* in the dictionary - are those strings? if so, shouldn't they be quoted?

In other words, try this:

```
function (doc, meta) {
    if(doc.type=='notification' && doc.channels){

        for (var user in doc.channels) {
            emit(user, {
                "alert": doc.alert,
                "body": doc.body,
                "seen": doc.seen,
                "timestamp": doc.timestamp
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried this, but still get {"total_rows":225784,"rows":[
]
}

Comment: lets break it down to pieces. You should first make sure that your function works well - meaning that it outputs something at all. And only later you should use a query to limit that output. I suggest you use the couchbase web UI to see the result of your view (not your code). What output are you getting form it? there should be a link that opens the view results in another tab and prints out 10 of the results by default. what do you see?

Comment: I am using couchbase web UI, when i run this query without any key parameter it gives result, after then i use key from result set and try to run agian it gives {"total_rows":225784,"rows":[ ] }

Comment: can you provide an example of the output? just a line or two from your view's results?

Comment: result when i didnt use any key:- {
"total_rows":220,
 "rows":[
  {
  "id":"notification::53aef3f78cb80cdb602",
  "key":"0",
  "value":{
   "alert":"smeagol reported \"hot\" at  Demo All Manager",
    "body":{
     "created_by":"user_52ca436db68ec76a33a26bc5",
     "description":" reported ",
     "summary":"hot",
     "username":"smel"
    },
   "channels":[
    "user_53a06ba16694f16de1b9cb21"
   ],
    "seen":false
  }
  }
 ]
}

when i use key user_53a06ba16694f16de1b9cb21 it result :- {"total_rows":225784,"rows":[ ] }

Comment: it looks like the key emitted is `"0"` and not `"user_53a06ba16694f16de1b9cb21"` as you expected, perhaps a problem with your map function?